How to create multiple files from a single file using separators?
I am trying to generate multiple files from a .txt file with separators. In this case, the column separator is | and the record separator is: ║.
Each name value only appear once in the input.
This is the code I'm trying:
awk -F'║', -vOFS=, -vc=1 '
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "") {
            g[c]=i;
            f[c++]=$i
        }
    }
}
NR>2 {
    for (i=1; i < c; i++) {
        print $1,$2, $g[i] > "output_"f[i]".tex"
    }
}' biennalis.txt

The content of biennalis.txt is something like this:
name|content
║Is-id27-ref06-01-13-1914|El año de la muerte del rey Ozías vi al Señor sentado en un trono excelso y elevado, y sus haldas llenaban el templo. Unos serafines se mantenían erguidos por encima de él; cada uno tenía seis alas: con un par se cubrían la faz, con otro par se cubrían los pies, y con el otro par aleteaban, y se gritaban el uno al otro:

 \textquote{Santo, santo, santo, el Señor de los ejércitos: llena está toda la tierra de su gloria.}.

 Se conmovieron los quicios y los dinteles a la voz de los que clamaban, y la casa se llenó de humo.

 Yo dije:

 \textquote{¡Ay de mí, que estoy perdido, pues soy un hombre de labios impuros, y entre un pueblo de labios impuros habito: que al rey el Señor de los ejércitos han visto mis ojos!}

 Entonces voló hacia mí uno de los serafines con una brasa en la mano, que con las tenazas había tomado de sobre el altar, y tocó mi boca y dijo:

 \textquote{He aquí que esto ha tocado tus labios: se ha retirado tu culpa, tu pecado está expiado.}

 Y percibí la voz del Señor que decía:

 \textquote{¿A quién enviaré? ¿y quién irá de parte nuestra}?

 Yo contesté:

 \textquote{Heme aquí: envíame.}

 Dijo:

 \textquote{Ve y di a ese pueblo: \textquote{Escuchad bien, pero no entendáis, ved bien, pero no comprendáis.} Engorda el corazón de ese pueblo, hazle duro de oídos, y pégale los ojos, no sea que vea con sus ojos y oiga con sus oídos, y entienda con su corazón, y se convierta y se le cure.}

 Yo pregunté:

 \textquote{¿Hasta dónde, Señor?}

 Y él me contestó:

 \textquote{Hasta que se vacíen las ciudades y queden sin habitantes, las casas sin hombres, la campiña desolada, y haya alejado el Señor a las gentes, y cunda el abandono dentro del país. Aun el décimo que quede en él volverá a ser devastado como la encina o el roble, en cuya tala queda un tocón. Este tocón será semilla santa.}


║Is-id27-ref01-01-18-0045|Visión de Isaías, hijo de Amós, acerca de Judá y de Jerusalén, en tiempos de Ozías, Jotán, Ajaz y Ezequías, reyes de Judá.

 Oíd, cielos, escucha tierra, que habla el Señor: \textquote{Hijos he criado y educado, y ellos se han rebelado contra mí.

 El buey conoce a su amo, y el asno el pesebre de su dueño; Israel no me conoce, mi pueblo no comprende}.

 ¡Ay, gente pecadora, pueblo cargado de culpas, raza malvada, hijos corrompidos! Han abandonado al Señor, han despreciado al santo de Israel, le han vuelto la espalda.

The end result I expect is separate files, whose name is the content of the first column and the content is what is in the second column:
Is-id27-ref06-01-13-1914.tex
El año de la muerte del rey Ozías vi al Señor sentado en un trono excelso y elevado, y sus haldas llenaban el templo. Unos serafines se mantenían erguidos por encima de él; cada uno tenía seis alas: con un par se cubrían la faz, con otro par se cubrían los pies, y con el otro par aleteaban, y se gritaban el uno al otro:

 \textquote{Santo, santo, santo, el Señor de los ejércitos: llena está toda la tierra de su gloria.}.

...

Is-id27-ref01-01-18-0045.tex
Visión de Isaías, hijo de Amós, acerca de Judá y de Jerusalén, en tiempos de Ozías, Jotán, Ajaz y Ezequías, reyes de Judá.

 Oíd, cielos, escucha tierra, que habla el Señor: \textquote{Hijos he criado y educado, y ellos se han rebelado contra mí.

...

Etc ...
The error when executing the command is as follows:
awk: syntax error at source line 10
    context is
        print $1,$2, $g[i] > >>>  "output_"f <<< [i]".tex"
awk: illegal statement at source line 10


Why is there a comma after -F'║'?

Also, why are you passing that as the field separator if you really want the field separator to be |?

Does the first line really contain name|content without a ║ at the beginning of the next line? Is there really no | after Is-id27-ref06-01-13-1914?

The input file you provided doesn't appear to be a CSV, I don't know what "the separator for each file" means in "the column separator is | and the separator for each file would be: ║" nor how it relates to you using -F'║', as your field separator (is that trailing , supposed to be there?), using , as the OFS for what appears to be free-form text without quoting the output fields is a bad idea, and the input appears to be multi-line blocks which your script wouldn't handle correctly so you may want to ask a new question about how to parse your input file(s) in general.

@EdMorton What I want is to generate multiple files using the separator ║ .

Regarding "the separator ║" - is that Field Separator or Record Separator? Input Separator or Output Separator? i.e. are you referring to the value you want RS, ORS, FS, and/or OFS to have? Is your input really a bunch of multi-line blocks of text with empty lines throughout them as shown in the question? Whatever it is, please [edit] your question to make sure the example is accurate and provide all information, don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Your first non-header block starts with Is-id27-ref06-01-13-1914El año ... with no ║ before Is-id27-ref06-01-13-1914 and no | after it, but then your second block starts with ║Is-id27-ref01-01-18-0045|Visión ... which DOES have ║ before it and | after it. Is that correct that your records sometimes do and sometimes don't start with ║<id>| or is one of them wrong? Again, please [edit] your question to fix it or explain it.

Actually... you got answers to the question you asked about that error message, you should just accept one of them and then ask a new question about the rest of it.

@EdMorton ║ is the record separator. As for |, sorry, there was one missing at the beginning of the file, I've already edited it.

Does each name value only appear once in the input, like in the example you provided? If so please [edit] your question to say that, if not please edit your question to fix your example.

@EdMorton It's correct. Each name value only appear once in the input.

An unparenthesized expression on the right side of input or output redirection is undefined behavior and so different awks will do different things with it, some will do what you want while others will fail as you're currently seeing. Change this:
print $1,$2, $g[i] > "output_"f[i]".tex"

to this:
print $1,$2, $g[i] > ("output_"f[i]".tex")

to solve that specific problem.
The next problem you may encounter is that you're not closing output files as you go and so you may run into a limit on how many files a process can have open at once. To fix that change your loop to:
for (i=1; i < c; i++) {
    out = "output_"f[i]".tex"
    if ( !seen[out]++ ) {
        printf "" > out
    }
    print $1,$2, $g[i] >> out
    close(out)
}

The if statement with seen[] is to ensure the script empties any existing output file the first time your script writes to it - if you handle that outside of the script then you can remove that if statement.
Given the information you added in comments and assuming each name field is unique, it now sounds like this is what you need overall, using any awk and regardless of whether or not ║ or |s appear elsewhere in your input:
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/^║/,"") {
    close(out)
    pos = index($0,"|")
    out = "output_" substr($0,1,pos-1) ".tex"
    $0  = substr($0,pos+1)
}
NR > 1 { print > out }


$ awk -f tst.awk biennalis.txt

$ cat output_Is-id27-ref06-01-13-1914.tex
El año de la muerte del rey Ozías vi al Señor sentado en un trono excelso y elevado, y sus haldas llenaban el templo. Unos serafines se mantenían erguidos por encima de él; cada uno tenía seis alas: con un par se cubrían la faz, con otro par se cubrían los pies, y con el otro par aleteaban, y se gritaban el uno al otro:

 \textquote{Santo, santo, santo, el Señor de los ejércitos: llena está toda la tierra de su gloria.}.

 Se conmovieron los quicios y los dinteles a la voz de los que clamaban, y la casa se llenó de humo.

 Yo dije:

 \textquote{¡Ay de mí, que estoy perdido, pues soy un hombre de labios impuros, y entre un pueblo de labios impuros habito: que al rey el Señor de los ejércitos han visto mis ojos!}

 Entonces voló hacia mí uno de los serafines con una brasa en la mano, que con las tenazas había tomado de sobre el altar, y tocó mi boca y dijo:

 \textquote{He aquí que esto ha tocado tus labios: se ha retirado tu culpa, tu pecado está expiado.}

 Y percibí la voz del Señor que decía:

 \textquote{¿A quién enviaré? ¿y quién irá de parte nuestra}?

 Yo contesté:

 \textquote{Heme aquí: envíame.}

 Dijo:

 \textquote{Ve y di a ese pueblo: \textquote{Escuchad bien, pero no entendáis, ved bien, pero no comprendáis.} Engorda el corazón de ese pueblo, hazle duro de oídos, y pégale los ojos, no sea que vea con sus ojos y oiga con sus oídos, y entienda con su corazón, y se convierta y se le cure.}

 Yo pregunté:

 \textquote{¿Hasta dónde, Señor?}

 Y él me contestó:

 \textquote{Hasta que se vacíen las ciudades y queden sin habitantes, las casas sin hombres, la campiña desolada, y haya alejado el Señor a las gentes, y cunda el abandono dentro del país. Aun el décimo que quede en él volverá a ser devastado como la encina o el roble, en cuya tala queda un tocón. Este tocón será semilla santa.}

$ cat output_Is-id27-ref01-01-18-0045.tex
Visión de Isaías, hijo de Amós, acerca de Judá y de Jerusalén, en tiempos de Ozías, Jotán, Ajaz y Ezequías, reyes de Judá.

 Oíd, cielos, escucha tierra, que habla el Señor: \textquote{Hijos he criado y educado, y ellos se han rebelado contra mí.

 El buey conoce a su amo, y el asno el pesebre de su dueño; Israel no me conoce, mi pueblo no comprende}.

 ¡Ay, gente pecadora, pueblo cargado de culpas, raza malvada, hijos corrompidos! Han abandonado al Señor, han despreciado al santo de Israel, le han vuelto la espalda.


The execution of cat command fails with this error: zsh: parse error near \}'`

You're doing something other than what I show, nothing in the commands I show could produce that error. Please show exactly the command you're trying to execute.

I'm trying to execute cat tst.awk and the other lines of code that follow: sub(/^║/,"") { etc ...

cat is a Unix command to display the contents of a file. I have a file named tst.awk that contains my awk script and so cat tst.awk is a command that will show you the contents of that file, i.e. my awk script. Save the awk script in a file named tst.awk and run it as awk -f tst.awk biennalis.txt as I show. Or you can do awk '... script inline ...' biennalis.txt if you prefer.

Ok. It's working for me now. And it gives me the advantage of being able to pass the file name as a parameter, which makes the code more practical. Thanks a lot.

Your script appears to be doing something quite different than what you are attempting. Assuming that the actual input file is well-formatted, let's ditch what you had and try again.
awk 'FNR==1 { next }
  /[║|]/ { split($0, n, /║/);
    if(f) { print n[1] >>f; close(f) }
    split(n[2], m, /\|/);
    f = "output_" m[1] ".tex"; print m[2] >>f; next }
f { print >>f; next }
{ print "orphan input: " $0 }' biennalis.csv

This splits any line with ║ or | in it, and uses the first field as the base of the new file name. It takes anything before ║ and appends that to the previously open file if there was one, so the delimiter can occur anywhere in a line; but this will break in peculiar ways if a line contains more than one of each delimiter.
This crucially assumes that you have a ║ before the first entry and | between the file name and the text you want in that file.
Demo: https://ideone.com/jsRJKf

My original answer works fine on Linux, but not on MacOS:
awk 'BEGIN { RS="║"; FS="|" }
  FNR > 1 { o = "output_" $1 ".tex"; print $2 >>o; close(o) }' biennalis.csv

We simply instruct Awk to use the proper record and field separators, and then instruct it to print the second field to a file whose name is derived from the first.
As above, for this to work, you have to have a ║ before the first entry and | between the file name and the text you want in that file.
Demo: https://ideone.com/LU1y4Y

My original answer works fine on Linux, but not on MacOS Likely GNU awk vs BSD awk / onetrueawk.

More likely mawk on Debian out of the box, but I haven't checked.

Thanks for your reply. The first code works as expected, but ignores the first case, creating only the files starting from the second separator ║. How could I make it take into account all of them, including the first one?

Is fixing the input file so it follows the format you specified out of the question?

Try this; very minor change. https://ideone.com/CXIoDg

Ok, the problem was a formatting error in the biennalis.csv file. The first code works as expected. Thanks.
